# Как написать код, при котором бот забирает/выдаёт роли discord?

Tags: python, discord, бот

Подскажите пожалуйста, только неделю назад начал осваивать коды и писать бота, хотелось бы написать бота который сможет выдавать и забирать роли, что-бы данная команда была доступна только админам. Всё что пришло в голову ниже прикрепил, но не работает ;(
[image: Моё "творчество"]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from disocrd.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
await ctx.send('pong')

@client.command()
async def addrole (ctx,role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
await user.add_role(role)
await ctx.send(f"{Роль выдана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")

@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
await user.remove_role(role)
await ctx.send(f"{Роль убрана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")





bot.run('Token')
```

Comment: Вы, мне кажется не знаете базового синтаксиса питона. Для начала следует подучить его. Например здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python или на любом другом ресурсе

Answer (score 1):

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from disocrd.utils import get

Не тут ошибка? from [!] "disocrd.utils" [!]
Исправь на discord.utils

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Правильно]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Запомни: В Python отступы играют огромную роль в написании кода, которых у тебя нет. Это все равно, что фигурные скобки в JS или Java - они дают понять компилятору где сравнение, а где def функция и прочее.
Вот исправленный код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from disocrd.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
 await ctx.send('pong')

@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx,role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
 if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
  await user.add_role(role)
  await ctx.send(f"Роль выдана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")

@client.command()
async def removerole(ctx, role: discord.role, user: discord.member):
 if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
  await user.remove_role(role)
  await ctx.send(f"Роль убрана! {role.mention} to {user.mention}.")


bot.run('Token')
```